# Fill a stacked boxplot of a dataframe by a column of another dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get a figure of boxplots for each of the columns of my dataframe:

```
sampleA    sampleB    sampleC    sampleD
  1          2           3          4
  3          2           8          9.5
  2.3        4           5.6        7
  9          2.1         6          15.7
  18.1       4.8         10         22.2
```

Then, I have another dataframe where I specify some features of this samples:

```
sampleID    FeatureA    FeatureB    FeatureC
sampleA       C            B          D
sampleB       C            A          R
sampleC       D            E          V
sampleD       M            B          T
```

How can I get a boxplot for each column of the first dataframe in the same picture, coloured by FeatureA (both the boxplot and its corresponding  x axis tick) of the second dataframe?

I have been trying:

```
ggplot(stack(df1), aes(x = ind, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill=df2$FeatureA)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, colour=df2$FeatureA))
```

But, this is not colouring my boxplots

This part `geom_boxplot(fill=df2$FeatureA)` just works if instead of FeatureA, I use a vector with colour names substituting the values of thIs factor.

This part `theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, colour=df2$FeatureA))` is not colouring the x ticks in the right order

I have also tried:

```
ggplot(stack(df1), aes(x = ind, y = values), fill=df2$FeatureA) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, colour=df2$FeatureA))
```

but the `fill` argument is not colouring at all.

Moreover, I don't get a legend with none of this commands:

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
         ~sampleA, ~sampleB, ~sampleC, ~sampleD,
                1,        2,        3,        4,
                3,        2,        8,      9.5,
              2.3,        4,      5.6,        7,
                9,      2.1,        6,     15.7,
             18.1,      4.8,       10,     22.2
         )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~sampleID, ~FeatureA, ~FeatureB, ~FeatureC,
  "sampleA",       "C",       "B",       "D",
  "sampleB",       "C",       "A",       "R",
  "sampleC",       "D",       "E",       "V",
  "sampleD",       "M",       "B",       "T"
  )



df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(1:4,names_to = "sample", values_to = "values") %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("sample" = "sampleID")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample, y = values, fill = FeatureA)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = c("red","red","green","blue")))
```

[image]